# How to check multidimensional array for equality with a user-input string?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the first part of my code, which creates an array of randomly generated letters with a size specified by the user. What I need to do now is receive a string from the user, and test for equality of that string within the generated array. When it comes to testing for equality, I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
package arraySearcher;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayGenerator {

// method that gets input from user and creates a random array..
public static void createArray() {

    // sets size of array..
    System.out.print("How many columns and rows will you have in your square matrix?");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = keyboard.nextInt();
    char[][] userArray = new char[size][size];

    // fills array with random letters..
    Random randomLetter = new Random();
    char c = (char) (randomLetter.nextInt(26) + 'a');
    for (int row = 0; row < userArray.length; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < userArray[row].length; column++) {
            userArray[row][column] = (char) (randomLetter.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        }

    System.out.println("Below is your square matrix with randomly generated letters.");

    // prints array..
    for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
        for (int g = 0; g < userArray[i].length; g++) {
            System.out.print(userArray[i][g] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on `test for equality of that string within the generated array`? It doesn't really make sense to me. How can a string and a multi-dimensional array be equal? Are you trying to do a "Boggle" sort of thing?

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you trying to test whether the user's input equals one row of the array, or are you also checking columns, or is this like a Word Search puzzle where you can go in any direction?  In any case, you'll have to compare on a character-by-character basis, and you can use [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) to get each character from the input string.

Comment: Yes, a word search is a good way to look at it. It will need to test for equality right to left and vice versa, up and down and vice versa, and diagonally.

Comment: Once equality is found, I would like the string(s) within the array to be converted to uppercase, and then be reprinted to the screen as well

Comment: Check this out: http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~drum/cs1112/lectures/module2/suppl/index.html Scroll down to the section titled "2D array of chars". It only demonstrates how to search horizontally but you can generalize the solution to search vertically and diagonally.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys- this all looks very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
    char[] ch=new char[]{'a','b','c'};

    System.out.println(new String(ch).equals("abc"));
```

---

```
int SIZE = 3;

// row-wise

char[][] rowArray = new char[][] { { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, { 'l', 'm', 'n' }, { 'x', 'y', 'z' } };

System.out.println("check in rows");    
for (int i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(new String(rowArray[i]).equals("abc"));
}

// column-wise

char[][] colArray = new char[SIZE][SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < colArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rowArray.length; j++) {
        colArray[i][j] = rowArray[j][i];
    }
}

System.out.println("check in columns");
for (int i = 0; i < colArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(new String(colArray[i]).equals("bmy"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `userInput` is the string that you receive from the user and you've already filled the `userArray` as a two dimensional array of `char`, you can check if `userInput` equals one of the rows this way:

```
if( userInput.length() < size )
    return false;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    flag = true;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        if (userInput.charAt(j) != userArray[i][j])
            flag = false;
    if (flag == true)
        return true;
}
return false;
```